# Substitute a mock object for the metaclass of a class

Tags: python, mocking, metaclass

How can I **override the metaclass** of a Python class, with a `unittest.mock.MagicMock` instance instead?

I have a function whose job involves working with the metaclass of an argument:

```python
# lorem.py

class Foo(object):
    pass

def quux(existing_class):
    …
    metaclass = type(existing_class)
    new_class = metaclass(…)
```

The unit tests for this function will need to assert that the calls to
the metaclass go as expected, *without* actually calling a real class
object.

**Note**: The test case *does not care* about the metaclass's behaviour; it cares that `quux` retrieves that metaclass (using `type(existing_class)`) and calls the metaclass with the correct arguments.

So to write a unit test for this function, I want to pass a class object whose metaclass is a mock object instead. This will allow, for example, making assertions about how the metaclass was called, and ensuring no unwanted side effects.

```python
# test_lorem.py

import unittest
import unittest.mock

import lorem

class stub_metaclass(type):
    def __new__(metaclass, name, bases, namespace):
        return super().__new__(metaclass, name, bases, namespace)

class quux_TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @unittest.mock.patch.object(
                lorem.Foo, '__class__', side_effect=stub_metaclass)
    def test_calls_expected_metaclass_with_class_name(
            self,
            mock_foo_metaclass,
            ):
        expected_name = 'Foo'
        expected_bases = …
        expected_namespace = …
        lorem.quux(lorem.Foo)
        mock_foo_metaclass.assert_called_with(
                expected_name, expected_bases, expected_namespace)
```

When I try to mock the `__class__` attribute of an existing class, though, I get this error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1500, in start
    result = self.__enter__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1460, in __enter__
    setattr(self.target, self.attribute, new_attr)
TypeError: __class__ must be set to a class, not 'MagicMock' object
```

This is telling me that `unittest.mock.patch` is attempting to set the `__class__` attribute temporarily to a `MagicMock` instance, as I want; but Python is refusing that with a `TypeError`.

But **placing a mock object as the metaclass** is exactly what I'm trying to do: put a `unittest.mock.MagicMock` instance in the `__class__` attribute *in order that* the mock object will do all that it does: record calls, pretend valid behaviour, etc.

How can I set a **mock object in place of the `Foo` class's `__class__` attribute**, in order to instrument `Foo` and test that my code uses `Foo`'s metaclass correctly?

Comment: The best you can probably do is to create a mock class with the edited metaclass and replace it for the test.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do exactly what you want. As you can see an object's `__class__`  attribute is very special in Python, and even for ordinary instances there are checks in runtime to verify it is assigned to a proper type. 
When you get down to a class's `__class__`, that is even more strict.

## Possible approach:

One thing to do in  there is *not* pass a class to your test - but an object that is an instance from a crafted ordinary class, which will have an artificial `__class__` attribute. Even them, you will have to change your code from calling `type(existing_class)` to do `existing_class.__class__` directly. For an instance object to "falsify" its `__class__` anyway, you have to implement  `__class__` as a property on its class (or override `__getattribute__`; (the class itself will report its true metaclass, but an instance can return whatever is coded on the `__class__` property.

```
class Foo:
    @property
    def __class__(self):
        return stub_metaclass
```

## Actual suggestion:

But then, since you are at it, maybe the simplest thing is to mock `type` instead on the target module where `quux` is defined.

```
class MockType:
    def __init__(self):
         self.mock = mock.Mock()
    def __call__(self, *args):
          return self.mock


...

class ...:
    ...
    def test_calls_expected_metaclass_with_class_name(
            self,
            ):
        try:
            new_type = MockType()
            # This creates "type" on the module "lorem" namespace
            # as a global variable. It will then override the built-in "type"

            lorem.type = new_type
            lorem.quux(lorem.Foo)
        finally:
            del lorem.type  # un-shadows the built-in type on the module
        new_type.mock.assert_called_with(
                'Foo', unittest.mock.ANY, unittest.mock.ANY)
```

## Still another approach

Another thing that can be done is to craft a full "MockMetaclass" in the "old fashion": without unittest.magicmock at all, instead, with intrumented `__new__`  and other relevant methods that will record the called parameters, and function as a true metaclass for a class you pass in as  parameter.

## Considerations on what is being done

People reaching here, please note that one should not test the class creation (and metaclass) mechanisms themselves. One can just assume the Python runtime have these working and tested already.

Comment: Thanks, this is a comprehensive response addressing the question.

Comment: “your tests seem to be all but testing the class creation (and metaclass) mechanisms themselves, not any code of yours.” — That's not true; the test case is asserting *whether* `quux` gets the correct metaclass, i.e. whether it uses `type(exising_class)`; and *what arguments* are passed when `quux` calls that metaclass. (I've updated the question to make that clearer.) So the test case doesn't care how the metaclass responds, it's testing `quux`'s retrieval of and use of that metaclass.

Comment: Nice - that is complicated to perceive.  I will shorten the considerations part - but leave something - for third-parties that hit this answer them

Comment: Putting a mock object in place of `type` also doesn't work, because the code *also* uses `type` to test whether objects are types. `assert isinstance(foo, type)` will fail when `type` is a mock object. I have updated the question to show this.